# I created a form and that form data is not going to grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, frontend, forms

Here is the code

doctorsform.phtml

```
<div class="myform" style="top:47px" >
               <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 contact-custom nopadding banner">
                  <h3>Instant Appointment, Please Fill Details Below.</h3>
                  <div class="contact_form mhc" style="height:275px">
                      <form name="doctorform" class="form form-signup"  action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('surgery/Secondindex/doctors'); ?>" method="post"  novalidate>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                           <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                              <input type="hidden" value="MRI" name="form_code">
                               <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>">
                        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="bmscheckbot">
                        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="bmsvaluebot" value="sanBMS">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                 <input  name="name" id="nameid" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control required-entry validate-alpha" type="text">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                           <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-mobile" ></i></span>
                                 <input name="phone" id="phoneid" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" class="form-control required-entry validate-phoneStrict validate-length minimum-length-10" type="text">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                           <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>
                                 <input type="file" class="form-control input-xxlarge" id="bs_image" name="bms_file" style="display:none;" required="">
                                 <input type="text" style="text-align: left;" id="bsvalimg" class="form-control" value="Upload prescription" onclick="document.getElementById('bs_image').click();">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="position:relative">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 g-veri scans" style="top:-7px">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                           <form action="http://www.bookmyscans.in/doctors-thankyou">
                           <button type="submit" id="mriscan-btn" class="btn btn-default custom" style="height:50px">SUBMIT</button></form>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

SecondindexController.php

```
public function doctorsAction(){
        $data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if($data['phone']!="" && $data['name']!=""){
                            $currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()); //Magento's timestamp function makes a usage of timezone and converts it to timestamp
                            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $currentTimestamp);
                            $data['created_time']=$date;
                            $data['source_from']='Website';
                            $data['status']=1;
                            $model = Mage::getModel('surgery/customer');
                            $model->setdata($data);
                            $this->_redirect('doctors-thankyou');
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Data has been submitted');
                        }
                        else{
                            $this->_redirectReferer();
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('please fill all the details');
                        }
}
}
```

Comment: are you able to reach to controller ? i.e when click submit going to controller

Comment: yeah, i forgot to save the data.   $model->setdata($data)->save(); by adding this line it works fine now

Comment: great!...... :)